# Multiple Tomcat instances: Port already in use: 8086 (tried checking server.xml)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have to run multiple Tomcat instance on app server (Apache Tomcat 7.0.33 and 7.0.42). Everything was working until last week. Now when I start one instance, another throws following error and couldn't start tomcat instance, and vice-a-versa. I thought of changing the port from 8086 to other, but there is no mention of port 8086 in both instance's config (conf/server.xml) files. How can I keep both instances running, without killing another instance?

Error:
2017-06-06 11:09:17 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 8086; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved by removing one third party application which was using 8086 port. This port was mentioned in Java tab -> Java Options of the Apache Tomcat Properties.

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086

Answer (score 0):

ensure the ports at file server.conf under tomcatdir/conf/  different than your other tomcat instance.